# Почему появляется ошибка "Command not found" при запуске bash-скрипта в Windows 10?

Tags: bash, git-bash

Есть простой bash-скрипт, который должен выводить одно слово:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при запуске скрипта выводится ошибка ""Command not found"".
С чем это может быть связано и как запустить скрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./g.sh` для скриптов не лежащих в `$PATH` нужно указать полный или относительный путь